# Catalog page based on attributes

Tags: magento2

We sell shoes. Inside our store we have 3 main categories:

1. men
2. women
3. kids

In our old Magento 1 the old dev found a way to create a catalog page not based on categories, but based on attributes. For example, all shoes with NIKE attribute would end up on a page like this: domain.com/brand/nike

Is there a way to do something like this in Magento 2? Like a module or a script?

My current DEV suggested to create a new category and add all products in each categories (which is foolishness, since we have over 400 brands and new products added every week).

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I see two way of doing this

1 - Each one of your 3 main category would get All the brands as sub categories. This way you just add it normally (without adding product to a category who doesn't need a product).

Advantage : Easy to setup
Drawbacks : Depending on your brands you might have a number of category too important.

2 - Lets do it from scratch
Create a new module and a new route that will take the brand.
And associate it with a custom template where you load the products the way you want.

Advantage : More light and powerfull for what you want.
Drawback : Heavy to setup cause you have to recode all the template and filters and sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using ElasticSuite (free module):

https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite

Using the virtual categories functionality:

https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/wiki/VirtualCategories